# My getline couldn't get the answer

Tags: c++

> 1. At first, it was all fine until I add the for function in a correct order.
> 2. When I tried to reverse it, I got all pre_dates correctly but the other output are totally wrong.
> 3. How do I recognize a word in a string?

**My output(2012):** 
avg. minimum temperature : 0 C
avg. maximum temperature : 0 C
Total Rainfall : 1.28
Days where reported weather is:
     Clear 1875655169
     Rain 0
     Snow 18

```
`string thedate, type, line;
int pre_date, ClearDays, SnowyDays, RainyDays;
double lowTemp = 0, highTemp = 0, totalrain = 0, avg_max = 0, avg_min = 0;
system("cls");


    ifstream myfile("weather.txt");

    if(!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout <<"Error opening file.";
    }
    else
    {
    for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
    {
        while(myfile >> pre_date >> thedate >> type >> lowTemp 
                     >> highTemp >> totalrain)
                {   
                    double avg_min = lowTemp++;
                    double avg_max = highTemp++;

                    getline(myfile, line); 
                    if (line==" ") //error checking
                    {
                        cout << " Error" << endl;
                        ClearDays=0; //if not true
                        RainyDays=0;
                        SnowyDays=0;
                    }
                    else 
                    {   
                        ClearDays++;
                        RainyDays++;
                        SnowyDays++;
                        totalrain++;
                    }       
                }   

    cout <<"Year: " <<pre_date<< endl;
    pre_date++;
    cout <<"\t Avg. minimum temperature: " <<avg_min<<" C" <<endl;
    cout <<"\t Avg. maximum temperature: " <<avg_max<<" C" <<endl;
    cout <<"\t Total rainfall: " <<totalrain<< endl;
    cout <<"\t Days where reported weather is: " << endl;
    cout <<"\t\t Clear       "<<ClearDays<<endl;
    cout <<"\t\t Rain        "<<RainyDays<<endl;
    cout <<"\t\t Snow        "<<SnowyDays<<endl;                        

    }               
}`
```

Comment: "My output is wrong"...  please show input and output, don't just describe it.

Comment: Sorry.. this is my first time here.. My output for year 2012: avg. minimum temperature : 0 C avg. maximum temperature : 0 C Total Rainfall : 1.28 Days where reported weather is: Clear 1875655169 Rain 0 Snow 18

Comment: Maybe you should initialize these: `ClearDays, SnowyDays, RainyDays;` If  your first line is not `line==" "`  these will have garbage data.

Answer (score 0):

Most often than not , if you're using repetitive getline operator you might want to clear the cin buffer as it might have left over data from you previous entry

use the : "cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()" statement to fix this and see if it works.